# How to add android Toolbar to an Activity that has a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I created a new Project in Android Studio - a Blank Activity with Fragment. It created the following files

- MainActivty.java MainActivityFragment.java activity_main.xml
  fragment_main.xxml

Now I wanted to add a Toolbar so I created a app_bar.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I modified the MainActivity.java as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.lalapetstudios.udacityprojects.spotifystreamer.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this. I get the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.CharSequence
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object
>   reference

So I modified my activity_main.xml as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
      android:id="@+id/app_bar"
      layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.lalapetstudios.udacityprojects.spotifystreamer.MainActivityFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Also modified the app_bar.xml as follows (removed the android:id parameter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Now the App runs. Im able to see the Toolbar. However the Fragment is hidden behind the tool bar. The HelloWorld is behind the Toolbar. How do I fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Try to set _android:orientation="vertical"_ in your LinearLayout

Comment: You should set android:orientation="vertical" in your LinearLayout of activity_main.xml 
This will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation to vertical in the activity_main.xml file. See below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
      android:id="@+id/app_bar"
      layout="@layout/app_bar" />

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/fragment"
      android:name="com.lalapetstudios.udacityprojects.spotifystreamer.MainActivityFragment"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
```